# connecting to viagenie servers with webRTC (needs username and credentials??)

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Hi I am having this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Both
>   username and credential are required when the URL scheme is "turn" or
>   "turns".
>       at https://connectah.com/js/script.js:23:10

```
//Create an account on Viagenie (http://numb.viagenie.ca/), and replace 
{
  'urls': 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
  'credential': 'websitebeaver',
  'username': 'websitebeaver@email.com'
}
//with the information from your account

var servers = {
  'iceServers': [{
    'urls': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'
  }, {
    'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  }, {
    'urls': 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
    '******': 'connectah',
    'raplizard97@gmail.com': 'raplizard97@gmail.com'
  }]
};

var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

please help.. i am wondering why its doing this?

Comment: @kgangadhar still getting the same error? i entered my username and pass ? this webrtc demo is from https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/simple-webrtc-video-chat-using-firebase

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
{
    'urls': 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
    '******': 'connectah',
    'raplizard97@gmail.com': 'raplizard97@gmail.com'
}
```

You need to have this instead:

```
{
    'urls': 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
    'credential': '<your TURN password>',
    'username': '<your TURN username>'
}
```

where `<your TURN password>` and `<your TURN pusername>` need to be replaced with your TURN password and username, respectively.